# UIAlertView shown on Home Screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, uialertview

Is there a way to have alert views pop up while the app is running in the background? The problem with Apple Push Notifications is the need for an internet connection. What is the best way to have local notifications without the need of an internet connection or server to push them out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have a look into [UILocalNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html)?

Comment: Thanks! This looks like what I need but it still does not support a uialertview with an image. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use local notification, but you have to set a specific time for them to popup...